# Property 'does not exist on type 'DishdetailComponent'

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm using angular 9 and i got an error.

```
ERROR in src/app/dishdetail/dishdetail.component.ts:81:9 - error TS2339: Property 'comment' does not exist on type 'DishdetailComponent'.
```

I want to show a real-time preview of the comment on the page. Here is my code.

```
dishdetail.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Params, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';
import { DishService } from '../services/dish.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Review } from '../shared/review';
import { Comment } from '../shared/comment';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-dishdetail',
  templateUrl: './dishdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dishdetail.component.scss']
})
export class DishdetailComponent implements OnInit {

  reviewForm: FormGroup;
  review: Review;
  @ViewChild('rvwform') reviewFormDirective;
  
  dish: Dish;

  formErrorss = {
   'author': '',
   'comment': ''
  };

  validationMessagess = {
    'author': {
      'required':  'Name is required.',
      'minlength':  'Author name must be at least 2 characters long.'
    },
    'comment': {
      'required':  'Comment is required.',
      'minlength': 'Comment must be at least 5 characters long.'
    }

  }

  constructor(private dishService: DishService, private location: Location, private route: ActivatedRoute, private rf: FormBuilder) {
     this.createReview();
   }

   createReview(){
     this.reviewForm = this.rf.group({
      'author': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)] ],
      'comment': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)] ] 
     });
     
     this.reviewForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));

    this.onValueChanged();

   }

   onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if (!this.reviewForm) { return; }
    const form = this.reviewForm;
    for (const field in this.formErrorss) {
      if (this.formErrorss.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        // clear previous error message (if any)
        this.formErrorss[field] = '';
        const control = form.get(field);
        if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
          const messages = this.validationMessagess[field];
          for (const key in control.errors) {
            if (control.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              this.formErrorss[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  onSubmit(reviewForm) {
   this.review = this.reviewForm.value;
   this.comment.date = new Date().toISOString();
   console.log(this.review);
   this.dish.comments.push(this.comment)
   this.reviewForm.reset({
     author: '',
     rating: 5,
     comment: '' 
   });
   this.reviewFormDirective.resetForm();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.dishService.getDish(id)
      .subscribe(dish => this.dish = dish);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

}
```

Here is my code for Review.ts

```
Review.ts

export class Review{
    author: string;
    rating: number;
    comment: string;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97zb0.png)

Upon submitting the valid comment, the comment should join the regular comments on the page. But im face  Property 'comment' does not exist on type 'DishdetailComponent'. Please guide me. Also please check i'm updated the question.

```
dish.ts
import { Comment } from './Comment';

export class Dish {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    image: string;
    category: string;
    featured: boolean;
    label: string;
    price: string;
    description: string;
    comments: Comment[];
}
```

This is dishdetails.ts

```
dishdetails.ts
export class Dishdetails{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    image: string;
    category: string;
    featured: boolean;
    label: string;
    price: string;
    description: string;
    rating: number;
    comment: string;
    author: string;
    date: string;
}
```

This is comment.ts

```
comment.ts
export class Comment {
    rating: number;
    comment: string;
    author: string;
    date: string;
}
```

Please check below image for error in my command line.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using "this.comment.date" inside OnSubmit(), but "comment" is not defined.
First declare comment.

**Or** it looks like you want to do this (as date is not used):

```
   this.review = this.reviewForm.value;
   //this.comment.date = new Date().toISOString();   //Comment this
   console.log(this.review);
   this.dish.comments.push(this.review)              //changed from this.comment
```

**Additionally,** If you're looking to add date in comment, then I suggest to change -

```
class Review{
    author: string;
    rating: number;
    comment: string;
}
```

**TO**

```
 class Review{
   author: string;
   rating: number;
   comment: string,
   date: string
  }
```

Comment: Not solved. It still shows ''ERROR in src/app/dishdetail/dishdetail.component.ts:81:9 - error TS2339: Property 'comment' does not exist on type 'DishdetailComponent'.".

Comment: Have you commented below line ?
   //this.comment.date = new Date().toISOString();   //Comment this
   & changed below one?
   this.dish.comments.push(this.review)              //changed from this.comment

Comment: Yes. I tried all that you mentioned but still same error occurred. Also please check i updated a question.

Comment: Still this line- 'this.comment.date = new Date().toISOString();' is giving error as you've not defined comment. Its where you're getting error.

Comment: Please check my updated question. I uploaded a screenshot of error.